# Different threshold levels for PMD rule

Tags: java, pmd

Is there way to report pmd error using two threshold levels

Problem: we have decided that the maximum cyclomatic complexity allowd for methods will be 11 if  a method has cyclomatic complexity greater that 11 it will be reported in PMD with priority 2 this rule works

Now we need to be able to list all methods whose cyclomatic complexity is greater than 8  and less than 11 (say with priority 4)so that there will be a warning in PMD report.

Is there a way to realise this with PMD?

Thanks and Regard

amp

Answer (score 1):

The current parameters of the rule only have a minimun threshold, so with the current implementation, your approach can be having twice the rule in your ruleset, one with threshold 11 (priority 2) and the other with threshold 8 (priority 4).
The problem of this approach, is that the methods with a cyclomatic complexity of 12 will generate 2 violations (one for each rule configuration).
Another possible approach could be the implementation of a new rule with a minimun and a maximum threshold, using PMD rule editor, but it'd take longer.